# How to add a ChangeHistory to all of my entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, annotations

I have a microservice with a little entity structure and a REST interface for my clients.

What I want is: **I want to track every change on specific primitive attributes in my entities.**

For example I have a entity Book with many pages.

Now a client changes the title of the book an the color of some pages and send an update request to the server.

What I wanna do, together (in the same transaction) with saving these changs to the database, is to add a row into the "book_changes" and "page_changes" table for every changed primitive attribute. A row like "**User X changed attribute Y from value R to value U**"

1. Is there a way to generically/automatically figure out what primitive attributes changed when I have to entities of the same class? Generics maybe?
2. How can I specify which attributes should be monitored? Are own Annotations "@MonitorChange" an option or do I do not have access to Annotations during runtime?
3. How do I make sure that this happens in one transaction with Spring Data JPA? Do I only have to add the @Transactional Annotation to my Service-Class or method like this?

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class BookService {
        
        @Transactional
        public Book updateBookWithPages(Book book){
            saveEntity(book)
            saveChangesToChangesTable(book.computeChanges())
       }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable tool for this is [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). You just annotate your entities or attributes as @Audited (and create audit tables for them) and envers takes care of the interceptors.